# How could I indexing python list of lists without concatenating?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, slice

Assume I have input like this:

```
bl = [[0,1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9], [10,11,12,13]]
idx = [10, 6, 3, 4, 9, 2]
```

and I want the output to be like this:

```
out = [[3,4,2], [6,9], [10]]
```

The logic behind is like this:

first I can view the `lb_cat` as some concatenated version:

```
lb_cat = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
```

Then index from the concatenated list:

```
pick = lb_cat[idx] = [10, 6, 3, 4, 9, 2]
```

At last, assigned the picked elements back to each group to get output of

```
 out = [[3,4,2], [6,9], [10]]
```

The difficulty is that I cannot use operations like concatenated, since my input is not standard python list and it does not support concatenation operations.

What I want to do is to pick from a list of objects with the indices from the 'concatenated' view, but I actually pick from each of the elements of the list `lb`.

How could I do that in an efficient python way?

===========
Edit:

I have implemented a slow version, like this:

```
import numpy as np
bl = [[0,1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9], [10,11,12,13]]
idx = [10, 6, 3, 4, 9, 2]
milestones = np.cumsum(np.array([len(el) for el in bl])).tolist()
milestones = [0,] + milestones

res = [[] for _ in bl]
for ix in idx:
    for i, m in enumerate(milestones):
        if ix < m:
            res[i-1].append(ix)
            break
```

This works for me, but it is too slow. Do I have a method to make it faster?

Comment: Keep in mind that most of the fast `numpy` code depends on arrays being 'rectangular', that is, n-dimensional.  It operates on the whole array is some fast standardized way.  Your `bl` contains lists of varying length.  That's a pretty good indication that some sort of Python level iteration is required.  Your iteration might well be as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your problem correctly, but I hope this will serve as a sufficient answer.

```
x=0   //to count the total number of numbers with concatination
out = []   //to store final result
for i in bl:
    temp = []
    for j in i:
        if x in idx:     //to check if you want xth indexed element
            temp.append(j)
        x+=1
    if len(temp)>0:      //only append if has an index in idx, i am not sure if you want this
        out.append(temp)
print(out)    //to print final output
```

Comment: What do you mean by `if x in idx` ? I hope I can use more efficient way, so I need to avoid naive for loops? Do I have other options please?

Comment: if x in idx checks if the element x is in the list idx. The run time here O(nm) where n is the total number of elements in bl and m is len(idx)